# How use PUT and INPUT numeric in SAS

Tags: types, sas, format

I have a issue with the cast using PUT and INPUT for some columns in a SAS table.

I trying to format :

```
               ###I need:          Using: 
tipdoc='01' -> tipdoc=1            input(tipdoc, 1.)
coddoc=1234 -> coddoc=00001234     put(coddoc, z8.)
```

but, I have this result :

```
tipdoc=0
coddoc=       .
```

Could you have some ideas? 
Thanks.

Comment: Is `coddoc` a character variable, or a numeric that should be displayed with leading zeros ?

Comment: Hello , coddoc is a numeric variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The informat tells `INPUT` how to interpret the incoming value. `1.` is selecting only the `0` digit and you get 0 numeric.  `coddoc` is already a number and only needs a format for showing the leading zeros, or maybe you want a character variable with leading zeros.

```
data want;

tipdoc='01';
coddoc=1234;

tipdoc_num = input(tipdoc,best12.);
format coddoc z8.;

coddoc_char = put (coddoc,z8.);

run;

ods listing;
proc print data=want;
run;

--------

                             tipdoc_    coddoc_
Obs    tipdoc      coddoc      num        char

 1       01      00001234       1       00001234
```

Answer (score 1):

You use a FORMAT to convert values to text.  You use an INFORMAT to convert text to values. Use FORMATs with the FORMAT and PUT statements and with the PUT() (and PUTN() and PUTC()) functions. Use INFORMATS with the INFORMAT and INPUT statements and with the INPUT() (and INPUTC() and INPUTN()) functions.

If `TIPDOC` is a character string then use an INFORMAT that is at least as wide as the longest value that the variable has.  Or to be safe you could just use the maximum width allowed by the informat you are using.

```
numberic_tipdoc = input(tipdoc,32.);
```

If `CODDOC` is a number then you could either use a format to display the value with leading zeros.  Or use the `PUT()` function to create a character variable with the formatted value.

```
format coddoc z8. ;
character_coddoc = put(coddoc, z8.);
```

If the converted value of CODDOC appears as a period then it had a missing value.  That is how SAS display missing numeric values.  You can use the `MISSING` option to tell SAS to display missing values using some other character.  For example to have it display it as a space use the command

```
options missing=' ';
```

before you use the PUT() function or print the value using other methods.

Or you could just make the program test if `CODDOC` is missing and then use a different value for the new variable.

```
character_coddoc = put(coddoc, z8.);
if missing(coddoc) then character_coddoc='missing';
```